# Неужели язык си не использует такое хранилище памяти как куча?

Tags: c

Я новичок в программировании.
Изучая языки C# и Java я постоянно сталкивался с таким понятием как куча и вот когда я стал изучать си, это понятие исчезло. Неужели язык си не использует такое хранилище памяти как куча?
Всем спасибо за ответы:)

Comment: Использует, malloc же

Comment: Спасибо большое,  как раз сегодня начал изучать malloc,  но самостоятельно не понял.

Comment: Да, язык С действительно не подразумевает наличия кучи. Вызов `malloc` совсем не обязательно означает выделение памяти из кучи.

Comment: @user7860670, формально в языке Си наверное ничего о куче нет,  однако, в `man malloc` (malloc это функция из стандартной библиотеки Си) написано -- *"Normally, malloc() allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts the size  of the heap as required, using sbrk(2).  When allocating blocks of memory larger than MMAP_THRESHOLD bytes, the glibc malloc() implementation allocates the memory as a  private  anonymous  mapping  using  mmap(2)"*

Comment: Спасибо большое